# Swift Create Dictionary Int: Class_Type

Tags: swift, class, dictionary, types

How can I create dictionary in Swift to map an integer to a class?

IE

```
var dict = [
    0: ClassOne,
    1: ClassTwo,
    2: ClassThree
]
```

Comment: How would you use the values when retrieving them from the dictionary? There is not much that you can do with a plain class type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the class type of the class `ClassOne` with `ClassOne.self`, so you should define your dictionary as follows:

```
var dict: [Int: AnyClass] = [
    0: ClassOne.self,
    1: ClassTwo.self,
    2: ClassThree.self
]
```

Comment: how do you instantiate with convenience initializers though

Comment: Try with the generic form of dictionary. For example: `var dict = Dictionary<Int, AnyClass>(dictionaryLiteral: (0, ClassOne.self))`.

Answer (score 0):

var dic : Int : Class = [ o : class1 , 1: class2 , 2 : class3]

Comment: var dic :  [ Int : class]  = [ 1: object]
to call some thin use this   dic[1]!.' any method'